# Good idea to host data that will be downloaded internationally using S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

I don't have any experience regarding server hosting performance and how slow it gets so I wanted to ask this question.

My situation is, I want to host a ~1MB data file that needs to be downloaded by clients occasionally (once every 2-3 days). Of course I would like to minimize costs as long as it does not hurt user experience too much. I have data to indicate that I have clients globally.

I wanted to ask what the ballpark figure would be for the amount of time it would take to download a file of this size from other parts of the world (data is hosted in the US). Does anyone have any idea, for instance, how long it would take to download a 1MB file from locations such as Japan?

In case people are wondering, I personally would consider it OK if it takes under 10s to download in most parts of the world.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do when you don't know how well something works... is to try it.  Create buckets in all of the regions, store a file, and then download it and see.

The official AWS-centric answer for global content distribution is to connect a CloudFront distribution to an S3 bucket, and set things up so that your content is downloaded from S3 *via* CloudFront.  This will tend to improve download speeds more when the user is distant from the bucket, even if the content isn't cached at a CloudFront edge, because most of the distance the download has to travel, it will be traveling on the AWS "Edge Network," a global network connecting CloudFront to the AWS regions, with fewer unknowns than the Internet at large between here and wherever.

I have a global client base, but -- for example -- my shopping pages' catalog images are stored in S3 in Oregon (us-west-2), but with links pointing to CloudFront.

Interestingly, the pricing for using both services together sometimes works out a little bit less expensive than using only S3.  A possible explanation for this is that edge network egress traffic represents a lower cost to AWS and the rates are set accordingly.  It's not a major difference, but once you understand the pricing tables, you'll see it.

Comment: I will setup some analytics to see how long it takes users to download the file from different regions. I wanted to ask here because it felt like something a lot of people have already tested themselves so I wanted to see if I could avoid doing it myself. Thanks though.

Comment: The problem with that is that you're venturing into "primarily opinion based" and subjective territory.  As you likely already know, the SO community tends to close questions as off-topic that go there.  You should be fine.

Comment: Note also an interesting display is available at the [S3 Transfer Acceleration Demo](http://s3-accelerate-speedtest.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/en/accelerate-speed-comparsion.html).  Importantly, this is for uploads, not downloads, but it's still interesting because S3 Transfer Acceleration uses exactly the same network and technology as CloudFront + S3,  but without the caching.  I should have mentioned it in the answer, as well, but so far I believe CloudFront + S3 is more advantageous than S3 with Transfer Acceleration enabled, because of the caching CloudFront provides.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to google around for something like that. I'm surprised there isn't one for download speeds based on locations. I didn't want it to get opinion based which is why I tried to define some specific constraints such as max time and exact locations.

Answer (score 1):

1MB in 10s equals 800kbps. I'd be very surprised if any reputable hosting provider couldn't keep up with that speed of delivery. Looking at [Akamai rankings (2015)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_Internet_connection_speeds#Akamai_Q3_2015_rankings)*, in Japan (as in your example) the average user's speed is 15Mbps: your file would then be downloaded in 0.53 seconds.

*( *Looking at the rankings, keep in mind that in countries where fast internet infra is yet to be ubiquitous, the "average speed" will be an average of fast corporate pipes and other premium links, with actual mainstream users having substantially slower speeds.)*

Then in most cases, this will be up to the user's connection speed, and further, their ISP's international links, which can be much slower than their national or regional pipes. More so in countries with less developed internet infrastructure, where operators are cutting costs and corners.

In deciding if you need to deploy S3 or other CDN solutions, or no extra solutions at at all, you'll have to start with mapping up your user demographics. If there's a substantial sector from far-away countries with weak net infra, it makes sense. Otherwise, it doesn't seem likely that your target speed of 1MB/10s wouldn't be matched even without a special means of delivery.

If you have *some* but not *substantial* traffic from countries/regions where you reckon int'l traffic might be slower, and if you want to eliminate extra costs, I figure your users will survive even if it takes 15-20 seconds once in a blue moon as their speeds fluctuate. *(This is opinion-based relative to how picky your users are!)* In such a case, I'd only bother with a CDN if I wanted to improve speeds across the board, e.g. for all requests for static resources, not just a single file requested every couple of days. Would make a more substantial contribution towards the general user experience.

Comment: P.S. A thought to humor yourself with: Even without a CDN, chances are people in Japan, South Korea or Scandinavia would have the file downloaded faster than someone out there in rural 'murica! ^_^

Comment: Yep. That's precisely the question I am trying to answer (CDN or S3). I am already hosting a lot of files using a CDN so I know how much more expensive it can be which is why I am trying to see if I can save some money here by using just S3 instead. I do agree with you that, on paper that download speed should be easy to achieve so I'm very hopeful.

Comment: If the bottleneck is with your users' overall speeds, then obviously nothing you do at your end can make it faster for them. As far as S3/CDN, any reason you couldn't use the free service from CloudFlare? Gives you a global CDN, only with less bells and whistles than their paid plans. Seems to be more than sufficient for your one-file concern. https://www.cloudflare.com/plans/